# GTFS fares allocation depending on time

Tags: gtfs, opentripplanner

How can I allocate GTFS fares depending on the time e.g. off-peak/peak times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit way to handle different fares at different times of day within the context of GTFS. I see several discussions, the most comprehensive of which seems to be [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mtadeveloperresources/A1bdvX0jabk) (which is very old -- as of Nov. 2015, the most recent reply on the thread is from early 2011).

A workaround proposed there is to use multiple route IDs for each route, because `fare_rules` allows for a fare to be associated with a particular route. For instance, if the route ID was `X`, the trips that run during the peak might have a different route ID `X_peak` with a different entry in `fare_rules`.

Comment: Cool thanks i thought maybe there is a new way than using routeIds I will stick to it.